# Should I add `/dev/urandom` into PHP `open_basedir`?

Tags: php, apache-2.4, php.ini, open-basedir

My system is centos 7.4,with `Apache 2.4.6` and `PHP 5.4`.
I have following setting in `/etc/php.ini`

```
open_basedir =.:/tmp/:/var/lib/php/session/
session.save_path = "/var/lib/php/session"
session.entropy_length = 0
;session.entropy_file = /dev/urandom
```

I read [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.entropy-file) ,

> Note: Removed in PHP 7.1.0. As of PHP 5.4.0 session.entropy_file defaults to /dev/urandom or /dev/arandom if it is available. In PHP 5.3.0 this directive is left empty by default.

I am asking should I add `/dev/urandom` into `open_basedir`, such as:
 `open_basedir =.:/tmp/:/var/lib/php/session/:/dev/urandom/`?

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you don't need to,  unless your own PHP code needs to read from `/dev/urandom` with either the `include()` or `fopen()` or similar  functions.

AFAIK the  `open_basedir` restriction is only built into functions that will take any user (developer)  supplied file names as input. The session generator (and for instance other crypto functions that need random data) does  not read from just any filename, session.entropy_file needs to be set by an administrator and  it is very unlikely that  `open_basedir` restrictions have been applied to the specific code that will read random data from that session.entropy_file